# Get row from table for last date before date parameter if no row for date parameter or entries null

Tags: foxpro

I have table, which holds the exchange rates for currencies. There is also a `Date` column, which holds the currency exchange rates acquisition date.

For some dates there is a row, but no currency exchange rates and for some dates there is no row in that table.

To get the currency exchange rates for a specific date, I need to pass the date as parameter.

```
SELECT
    documentHead.r_art AS documentHeadDocClass,
    foreignCurrency.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
    foreignCurrency.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
    foreignCurrency.chf_brief AS foreignCurrencyCHFAsk,
    foreignCurrency.chf_geld AS foreignCurrencyCHFBid,
    foreignCurrency.gbp_brief AS foreignCurrencyGBPAsk,
    foreignCurrency.gbp_geld AS foreignCurrencyGBPBid,
    foreignCurrency.jpy_brief AS foreignCurrencyJPYAsk,
    foreignCurrency.jpy_geld AS foreignCurrencyJPYBid,
    documentListPeriods.id AS documentPeriodsID,
    documentListPeriods.von AS documentPeriodsFrom,
    documentListPeriods.bis AS documentPeriodsTo,
    documentListPeriods.tage AS documentPeriodsDays,
    documentListPeriods.rate AS documentPeriodsRate,
    documentListPeriods.wert AS documentPeriodsWorth
    FROM (
        SELECT  documentPeriods.id AS documentPeriodsID,
            documentPeriods.von AS documentPeriodsFrom,
            documentPeriods.bis AS documentPeriodsTo,
            documentPeriods.tage AS documentPeriodsDays,
            documentPeriods.rate AS documentPeriodsRate,
            documentPeriods.wert AS documentPeriodsWorth
        FROM comperiode AS documentPeriods
        WHERE documentPeriods.id = 1
) AS documentListPeriods
INNER JOIN tckopf AS documentHead ON documentHead.id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN devisen AS foreignCurrency ON foreignCurrency.datum = documentHead.datum
```

How can I get a currency exchange rates table row, where the currency exchange rates exists and the date is equal to the passed date parameter or the last date before the passed date parameter?

The problem is:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN devisen AS foreignCurrency ON foreignCurrency.datum = documentHead.datum
```

if the row for `foreignCurrency.datum` not exists or the currency exchange rates are `NULL`. If I use

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN devisen AS foreignCurrency ON foreignCurrency.datum <= documentHead.datum
```

I get all less than `foreignCurrency.datum`, but I only need the newest row.

In the following example there are missing rows for a date or a row where are all columns are `NULL`.:

[image: currencies exchange rates with missing values for a date]

If `documentHead.datum` is `2009-08-09` and there is no row for that date, I need newest row before. In that case the row for `2009-08-07`.

I tried to use `TOP 1` and a rewrite for the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like the following.:

```
SELECT  documentHead.r_art AS documentHeadDocClass,
    foreignCurrency.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
    foreignCurrency.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
    foreignCurrency.chf_brief AS foreignCurrencyCHFAsk,
    foreignCurrency.chf_geld AS foreignCurrencyCHFBid,
    foreignCurrency.gbp_brief AS foreignCurrencyGBPAsk,
    foreignCurrency.gbp_geld AS foreignCurrencyGBPBid,
    foreignCurrency.jpy_brief AS foreignCurrencyJPYAsk,
    foreignCurrency.jpy_geld AS foreignCurrencyJPYBid,
    documentListPeriods.id AS documentPeriodsID,
    documentListPeriods.von AS documentPeriodsFrom,
    documentListPeriods.bis AS documentPeriodsTo,
    documentListPeriods.tage AS documentPeriodsDays,
    documentListPeriods.rate AS documentPeriodsRate,
    documentListPeriods.wert AS documentPeriodsWorth
    FROM (
        SELECT  documentPeriods.id AS documentPeriodsID,
            documentPeriods.von AS documentPeriodsFrom,
            documentPeriods.bis AS documentPeriodsTo,
            documentPeriods.tage AS documentPeriodsDays,
            documentPeriods.rate AS documentPeriodsRate,
            documentPeriods.wert AS documentPeriodsWorth
        FROM comperiode AS documentPeriods
        WHERE documentPeriods.id = $P{document_id}
) AS documentListPeriods
INNER JOIN tckopf AS documentHead ON documentHead.id = $P{document_id}
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1
        foreignCurrency.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
        foreignCurrency.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
        foreignCurrency.chf_brief AS foreignCurrencyCHFAsk,
        foreignCurrency.chf_geld AS foreignCurrencyCHFBid,
        foreignCurrency.gbp_brief AS foreignCurrencyGBPAsk,
        foreignCurrency.gbp_geld AS foreignCurrencyGBPBid,
        foreignCurrency.jpy_brief AS foreignCurrencyJPYAsk,
        foreignCurrency.jpy_geld AS foreignCurrencyJPYBid
    FROM
        devisen AS foreignCurrency
    WHERE
        foreignCurrency.datum <= documentHead.$P!{exchangeRateTiming}
        AND foreignCurrency.datum IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.usd_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.usd_geld IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.chf_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.chf_geld IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.gbp_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.gbp_geld IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.jpy_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND foreignCurrency.jpy_geld IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY foreignCurrency.datum DESC  ) AS foreignCurrency
```

But then I get a null pointer exception in iReport.:

```
Error filling print... Error executing SQL statement for : boss_charterfaktura_document_list_interval_positions 
Setting up the file resolver...  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : boss_charterfaktura_document_list_interval_positions      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:246)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1086)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1253)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException      at com.hxtt.sql.dl.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.c3.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.aj.else(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.aj.cm(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.aj.s(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.dl.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.dl.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.el.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.dl.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.br.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.ai.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.dn.executeQuery(Unknown Source)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:239)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1086)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1253)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)        at com.hxtt.global.SQLState.SQLException(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.br.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.ai.a(Unknown Source)      at com.hxtt.sql.dn.executeQuery(Unknown Source)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:239)      ... 12 more  
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

How can I achieve that in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

This type of queries can be done using a derived table or a correlated subquery or in modern DBMS with window functions. Some DBMS have special proprietary extentions on the standard SQL syntax, like SQL-Server's `OUTER APPLY` and PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`, which can also be used to solve this kind of problems.

Since FoxPro does not have either of these, you could use the derived table approach or what I would call the *"poor man's `OUTER APPLY`"*:

```
SELECT 
    dh.r_art  AS documentHeadDocClass,
    fc.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
    fc.usd_geld  AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
    fc.chf_brief AS foreignCurrencyCHFAsk,
    fc.chf_geld  AS foreignCurrencyCHFBid,
    fc.gbp_brief AS foreignCurrencyGBPAsk,
    fc.gbp_geld  AS foreignCurrencyGBPBid,
    fc.jpy_brief AS foreignCurrencyJPYAsk,
    fc.jpy_geld  AS foreignCurrencyJPYBid,
    dp.id   AS documentPeriodsID,
    dp.von  AS documentPeriodsFrom,
    dp.bis  AS documentPeriodsTo,
    dp.tage AS documentPeriodsDays,
    dp.rate AS documentPeriodsRate,
    dp.wert AS documentPeriodsWorth
FROM
        comperiode AS dp                 -- documentPeriods
    INNER JOIN 
        tckopf AS dh                     -- documentHead 
            ON dh.id = dp.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        devisen AS fc                    -- foreignCurrency
            ON fc.datum =
               ( SELECT TOP (1) fci.datum
                 FROM devisen AS fci
                 WHERE fci.datum <= dh.datum 
                 ORDER BY fci.datum DESC 
               )
WHERE 
        dh.id = $P{document_id} 
  AND   dp.id = $P{document_id} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to add `ON` clause to the end:

```
SELECT  documentHead.r_art AS documentHeadDocClass,
    foreignCurrency.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
    foreignCurrency.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
    foreignCurrency.chf_brief AS foreignCurrencyCHFAsk,
    foreignCurrency.chf_geld AS foreignCurrencyCHFBid,
    foreignCurrency.gbp_brief AS foreignCurrencyGBPAsk,
    foreignCurrency.gbp_geld AS foreignCurrencyGBPBid,
    foreignCurrency.jpy_brief AS foreignCurrencyJPYAsk,
    foreignCurrency.jpy_geld AS foreignCurrencyJPYBid,
    documentListPeriods.id AS documentPeriodsID,
    documentListPeriods.von AS documentPeriodsFrom,
    documentListPeriods.bis AS documentPeriodsTo,
    documentListPeriods.tage AS documentPeriodsDays,
    documentListPeriods.rate AS documentPeriodsRate,
    documentListPeriods.wert AS documentPeriodsWorth
    FROM (
        SELECT  documentPeriods.id AS documentPeriodsID,
            documentPeriods.von AS documentPeriodsFrom,
            documentPeriods.bis AS documentPeriodsTo,
            documentPeriods.tage AS documentPeriodsDays,
            documentPeriods.rate AS documentPeriodsRate,
            documentPeriods.wert AS documentPeriodsWorth
        FROM comperiode AS documentPeriods
        WHERE documentPeriods.id = $P{document_id}
) AS documentListPeriods
INNER JOIN tckopf AS documentHead ON documentHead.id = $P{document_id}
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1
        fc.usd_brief AS foreignCurrencyUSDAsk,
        fc.usd_geld AS foreignCurrencyUSDBid,
        fc.chf_brief AS foreignCurrencyCHFAsk,
        fc.chf_geld AS foreignCurrencyCHFBid,
        fc.gbp_brief AS foreignCurrencyGBPAsk,
        fc.gbp_geld AS foreignCurrencyGBPBid,
        fc.jpy_brief AS foreignCurrencyJPYAsk,
        fc.jpy_geld AS foreignCurrencyJPYBidб
        fc.datum
    FROM
        devisen AS fс
    WHERE
        fc.datum <= $P!{exchangeRateTiming}
        AND fc.datum IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.usd_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.usd_geld IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.chf_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.chf_geld IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.gbp_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.gbp_geld IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.jpy_brief IS NOT NULL
        AND fc.jpy_geld IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY fc.datum DESC  ) AS foreignCurrency
ON foreignCurrency.datum = documentHead.datum
```

BTW, I do not like to re-use the aliases inside a sub-query and outside of it. Therefore I introduced an `fc` alias

Comment: In iReport I get.: `Error:SQL problems:Syntax error: Stopped parse at fc(id127)`.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try again